# Authorize.net card reader error

Tags: credit-card, authorize.net, cardreader

Hi I am getting Invalid cardNumber error when transaction is done using card reader or scanning.

```
The 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:cardNumber' element is invalid - 
The value '"CARD_NUMBER"' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - 
The actual length is greater than the MaxLength value.
```

But it works fine when the CC number is entered manually.
Could anyone please tell me what is the exact reason for this and how will i solve it?

Comment: Can you show the actual XML that is generated?

Comment: It is actually used in php web services for andriod app.

Comment: I am new to this.Have just made a function that carries out this web service

Comment: We can't help you until you provide us with the XML your code is generating. There has to be a way to get it.