# Authorize.net CIM error using Card.io

Tags: credit-card, authorize.net, card.io

While using card.io ios sdk for scanning the credit card, i am getting this error:

```
The 'AnetApi\/xml\/v1\/schema\/AnetApiSchema.xsd:cardNumber' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.Reason:
```

I get card number in this format: ••••••••••••1111 after scanning the card and normal whole 16 digit number when entered manually.
And the transaction is approved when i enter card details manually.
What is exactly going wrong can anyone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorize.net card reader error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191577/authorize-net-card-reader-error)

Comment: But there is no anser there and i am getting some other error here.

Comment: Can anyone just tell whether the error is because the API which we have used for Scan card fails to submit the scanned data to the Authorize.net